# インスタンスにprototypeは自動設定されない？　無理やり設定した場合は、普通のプロパティとして取り扱われる？

Tags: javascript

**質問背景**
・単なる興味本位
・インスタンスにprototypeは設定できないのかな、と思いました
・prototypeは予約語ではない(？)ので，普通のプロパティとして使用可能？
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

```
var Hoge = function(p1) {
 this.p1 = p1;
};

Hoge.prototype = {
  m1: function() {
    return this.p1;
  }
};

var hoge = new Hoge('プ1');
hoge.m1(); //"プ1"
```

---

・自動設定されない

```
hoge.prototype; //undefined
```

---

・インスタンスにprototypeは自動的に設定されないようなので、手動設定に挑戦
・目的はないです
・挙動確認したいためだけの単なる興味本位

```
hoge.prototype = {
  m2: function() {
    return this;
  }
};
```

---

・Function オブジェクトではないから？

```
hoge.m2(); //Uncaught TypeError: hoge.m2 is not a function(…)
```

---

・prototypeは予約語ではない(？)ので，普通のプロパティとして使用可能、ということでしょうか？

```
hoge.prototype.m2(); //Object {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ややこしいので、以下ではオブジェクトがプロパティを継承するオブジェクトを「プロトタイプ」、名前がたまたまprototypeであるプロパティを「prototypeプロパティ」と書きます。

オブジェクトの「prototypeプロパティ」は、そのオブジェクトの「プロトタイプ」ではありません。
おっしゃる通り、「prototypeプロパティ」は普通のプロパティです。
プロトタイプチェーンで「prototypeプロパティ」が参照される事はありません。
質問の例ですと、Hogeは「prototypeプロパティ」の m1 がありますが、m1 という名前でプロパティを参照しても、これは辿られません。

```javascript
Hoge.prototype;
// -> { m1: [Function] }
Hoge.m1();
// エラー
```

では、Hogeのプロトタイプテェーンで参照される「プロトタイプ」は何なのかというと、`Object.getPrototypeOf(Hoge)` で調べられます。Hogeは関数なので定義した時に処理系が`Function.prototype`を自動で設定しています。callプロパティ（メソッド）を調べると、プロトタイプテェーンでFunction.prototype.callが辿られているのが分かります。

```javascript
Object.getPrototypeOf(Hoge) === Function.prototype
// -> true
Hoge.call == Function.prototype.call
// -> true
```

では、「prototypeプロパティ」が普通のプロパティであるなら、いつ使われるかというと、new演算子がオブジェクトを作る時です。new は新しいオブジェクトの「プロトタイプ」にコンストラクタオブジェクトの「prototypeプロパティ」を設定します。

```javascript
hoge = new Hoge(1);
Hoge.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(hoge);
// -> true
```

このように、new が使う約束になっている事以外は「prototypeプロパティ」に特別な作用はないのです。

ただ、さらにややこしい事にブラウザによっては「__proto__プロパティ」という物があります。
これは本当にオブジェクトの「プロトタイプ」を参照しており、場合によって設定し直す事も可能です。

```javascript
hoge.__proto__ = {
  m2: function() {
    return this;
  }
};

hoge.m2()
// -> Object { p1: "プ1" }
hoge.m1()
// エラー: 
// hogeの「プロトタイプ」をnew演算子が設定した物(Hogeの「prototypeプロパティ」)
// と入れ替えたため。m1は辿れなくなった。
```

「__proto__プロパティ」は標準でなく（後から書き換えが可能な事から性能上の問題もあるらしいです）、使うべきではありません。

Answer (score 0):

prototypeについて誤解があるようです。
Functionオブジェクトのprototypeはそれで生成したオブジェクト(this)の"prototype"に設定されるわけではありません。
Javascriptは、オブジェクト自体に存在しないプロパティやファンクションは、そのコンストラクタのprototypeのプロパティやファンクションを探します。
hoge.constructor.prototypeにあなたの作成したm1というファンクションを持つオブジェクトが設定されているでしょう。

Comment: 質問の例ですと、constructorプロパティを使う場合は注意が必要です。関数定義時には、その関数オブジェクトの「prototypeプロパティ」の「constructorプロパティ」にその関数自身が設定されます。Hoge.prototype.constructor === Hoge がtrueです。ですから、これから生成されたhogeでは hoge.constructor === Hoge.prototype.constructor であり、hoge.constructor === Hoge です。しかし、質問の例ではHogeの「prototypeプロパティ」を新しいオジェクトにしていますので、Hoge.prototype.constructor === Object になっており、これ以降にHogeから生成している hoge では、hoge.constructor === Object となりhoge.constructor.prototype.m1 はありません。